# Certain protractor API functions cause errors

Tags: angular, protractor, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

Why am I receiving errors when I use Protractor API functions? I have scoured the internet for solutions to this problem and I found a couple similar answers, but they didnt work and so I'm asking the community.

I am trying to set up the simplest e2e test with Karma and Protractor. 
An empty block of test code like this will yield no error:

```
describe('Mapping Assistant State', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
   });

   it('should display a table',() => {
      console.log('test');
   });

   it('should click the create Paste button',() => {

    });
});
```

The problem occurs once I add certain functions from protractor like expect() or browser():

```
it('should display a table',() => {
    browser.get('someUrl');
    expect(element(by.css('.map')).getText()).toContain('map');

});
```

Here are some of the contents of my package.json:

```
"protractor": "^5.3.0",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.6",
"typescript": "^2.5.2"
"@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
"rxjs": "^5.4.3",
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.6",
"ts-node": "^4.0.1",
"@types/node": "^8.0.58",
```

Also:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
import {describe} from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';
import {beforeEach} from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';
```

Here is my `protractor.conf.js` file:

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    }
};
```

Once adding any of the Protractor functions and running 'ng test', these errors occur:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/saucelabs/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib-cov/SauceLabs' in '/Users/moop/Work/frontend/web/node_modules/saucelabs'
 @ ./node_modules/saucelabs/index.js 2:2-32
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/sauce.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/index.js
 @ ./e2e/sample.e2e-spec.ts
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/moop/Work/frontend/web/node_modules/protractor/built'
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js 54:32-56
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/index.js
 @ ./e2e/sample.e2e-spec.ts
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/bpRunner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/moop/Work/frontend/web/node_modules/protractor/built'
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/bpRunner.js 3:24-48
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/index.js
 @ ./e2e/sample.e2e-spec.ts
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/moop/Work/frontend/web/node_modules/protractor/built'
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js 67:32-56
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/index.js
 @ ./e2e/sample.e2e-spec.ts
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/moop/Work/frontend/web/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js 25:14-38
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/index.js
 @ ./e2e/sample.e2e-spec.ts
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/moop/Work/frontend/web/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io'
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js 20:21-45
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/protractor/built/index.js
 @ ./e2e/sample.e2e-spec.ts
 @ ./src/test.t
```

Does anyone have an idea about what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try removing those imports:  
import {describe} from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';
import {beforeEach} from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';

Comment: please share protractor.conf.js

Comment: @varunsingh I just added the protractor.conf.js to the question. Talavera, These errors persisted before I added the import for the selenium-webdriver.

Comment: @IanS did you ever find a solution for this? I'm seeing the same thing and the only answer below did not fix it for me.

Comment: In My case I had imported eventemitter from protractor. VSCode auto import did this issue. `import { EventEmitter } from "protractor";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install two more package: `@types/node` and `ts-node`

Comment: This had fixed it for me but others still have this error

Answer (score 52):

Some time we add event emitter then visual studio automatic added event-emitter liabrary.

like : `import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';` then auto generate protecter error.

solution : Remove auto import from own code and added  `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'`;

so error is wrong added liabrary for **EventEmitter** in our code.

Comment: this fixed my issue. i was dumb enough to trust the auto import.

Comment: Thanks dude. Headache saver.

Comment: I somehow knew that something is wrong with Protractor itself when the VSCode auto imported EventEmitter from the library the ```emit();``` function started asking for a parameter. Your answer resolves it. Thanks.

Comment: this is the cause in most of the cases, it fixed my issue as well

Comment: Thank you i've thinking I broke something YHO! thanks

Comment: THANKS A LOT! This was making me crazy.

Comment: It was `By` in my case but it was the same issue. You just saved me from a massive headache. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I was using 
import { By } from 'protractor';
and that caused all my troubles. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 5):

Check your logs carefully if it's saying

**LOG -** 
ERROR in ./node_modules/saucelabs/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib-cov/SauceLabs' in 'N:\Angular Codes\billmanagement\node_modules\ **saucelabs**'

ERROR in ./node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'N:\Angular Codes\billmanagement\node_modules\ **protractor**\built'

***SOLUTION -*** 

make sure in the app.module.ts you have imported correct version of Event Emitter
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

NOT THIS-  (usually Visual Studio does it automatically)
import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an Editor (such as VSCode) several automatic imports will create this problem.  In addition to the above answers, namely showing that this:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';
```

instead of this...

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

will give you said error.  But even this:

```
import { error } from 'protractor';
```

instead of this...

```
import { error} from '@angular/core';
```

will also give you the same result.  In my case, I didn't need an import!  I was trying to use the temporary variable name "error" in a catch statement and while typing that name, it automatically created an import from protractor.  (I have now resolved to use more specific names like say "myfuncerr").  So anything that autocompletes could potentially import from the wrong library.

If you are getting this error, the first thing to do is to do a global find on the word "protractor".  It is a fast fix (it would have saved me at least a couple of hours).

Comment: omg I had this issue, thanks! Saved me a load of time

Answer (score 1):

In my case, imported $ accidentally from protector instead jquery

Answer (score 0):

in my case, vs code makes accidental imports: import { promise } from 'protractor'